# Is the bootstrap estimate of the mean biased when a single extreme value is in the sample?

Tags: estimation, bootstrap, mean, bias, unbiased-estimator

My sample includes $n$ random observations, while $n-1$ of these observations are in the range (0-1)  there is also one observation that gets very high value.
For example, a sample of prices where $n-1$ prices are lower then 1 dollar and one price in the sample is 1000 dollars.

**Is the bootstrap estimate of the mean biased when a single extreme value such as above is in the sample?**

It seems to me that it should  depend on $n$ and $B$, where $B$ is the number of sub-samples.

Comment: I suspect that in the terminology used in statistics you mean "observation" when you say "variable". Multiple variables would mean that we take a look at a product and record it's price, weight, colour, etc. Each of these would be called a variable. I suspect you mean that you looked at multiple products or one products over multiple times (i.e. multiple observations) and you want to consider one characteristic (i.e. one variable): it's price. Is that correct? If so, can you edit your question?

Comment: By $B$ do you mean the number of repetitions of the bootstrap? Also, I'd like to hear your thought about how an extreme value would affect the bootstrap-estimated mean. Would you still have a question if we were talking only about a simple mean and not a bootstrap estimate of the mean? Would you still have the same question if there were no extreme value?

Comment: @Wayne, B is the number of repetitions. It seems to me that the extreme value is matter. Because of the extreme value the mean in the sample can be higher then 1 and it won't be included in the conferencing interval. But I really have no intuition for it.

Comment: How is that different than just the mean (without any bootstrapping)? I can't see how bootstrapping will make any difference (either for better or worse) as compared to the straight-up mean.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you believe your data. Such an extreme outlier could be a sign that something went wrong in the data collection (e.g. someone misunderstood the question) or data preparation (e.g. someone forgot to transform the prices in yen to euros for one of the products).

However, if the distribution of prices in the population has such a weird shape, then the mean will not be biased. You might want to think about whether or not the median will be a more meaningful measure of central tendency in such a distribution, but that is a different story.

Comment: If I do believe my data, can you please explain why the mean will not be biased? Thanks!

Comment: why would you think that the mean is biased?

Comment: There are 2 possibilities: it's unbiased estimator for the sample mean, and/or it's unbiased estimator for the mean in the population. Am I right? The problem is that I don't know how to check whether the estimator that I got in bootstrap is unbiased.